# Type or namespace name HttpPostedFileBase could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have  the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult BandRegister(BandProfileModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  return View(_profileService.CreateBandProfile(model, file));
}
```

Here is my service:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web;

public BandProfileModel CreateBandProfile(BandProfileModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
}
```

But Inside my service class, It keeps saying:

> Type or namespace name HttpPostedFileBase could not be found

I can't understand why. Have I not include all references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you're missing a reference to System.Web, which is where that type is defined.  Check your references, and add it if necessary.